# how to decrypt encrypted data from database in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

following is my code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

u = User.objects.get(username='test')
user.password
u'sha1$c6755$66fc32b05c2be8acc9f75eac3d87d3a88f513802
```

Comment: you can't decrypt this

Comment: why i cant i will decrypt and mail you

Comment: because Django uses PBKDF2 to encrypt passwords which is a one-way hashing algorithm

Comment: what should now i do to get original password without encrypt data

Comment: why do you want to get the original password?

Comment: You can't. If you want, you have to ask the user for his password :)

Comment: how to check given pasword is matched or not which stored in database password when we login.

Comment: Added an answer. Please read it

Comment: It is *not* encrypted. It is *hashed*. Hashing is a *one direction* function (well it should be a *one direction* function). Meaning once hashed, there is no *efficient* way to go the other way.